# Proper Way to format a thumbnail URL

Tags: rest

Can someone teach me how to follow good REST practices in formatting this URL?

This is a simple question. Is it improper to format a url for requesting a thumbnail by simply appending a "t" on the end?

```
GET /pictures/:picId/t
```

My thought process is that simply appending a "t" is not descriptive. Would it be more proper to have a URL like this?

```
GET /pictures/:picId/thumbnail
```

Or possibly this is irrelevant and either route is equally accepted?